# php script using fread() times out - was working fine for about a year, but now it's failing

Tags: php, download, timeout, fread

I'm using a session controlled script to allow users to get files from my server that are outside the web-readable area of the site. The problem lately has been that the files are never finishing. The browser says it's all done, but the files aren't complete. I'm on a shared host (Arvixe) and this is a new problem. They allegedly have extended the php timeout limit to an hour, but that hasn't helped.

Here's the code that does the work:

```
header("Content-length: $filesize");
header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
while( !feof ( $filetoget ) ) {
    $buff = fread ( $filetoget, 1024 );
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $buff;
}
fclose ($filetoget);
```

From a similar thread here I added these two lines, but that doesn't seem to have helped at all either:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

Comment: Does the error log give any hints? Have you tried changing the memory_limit?

Comment: Try with small files. Is it working?

Comment: Small files (25MB) work fine. I upped the chunk size to 8192 and got it to work. Haven't tried memory_limit and error log (at least what i have access to on this shared host) is empty.

Answer (score 0):

use `set_time_limit(0)`
it will make the script run forever (as long as needed)

Comment: I added that, but nothing changed. Thanks though.